# How to check if element exists after a certain time using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm newly in cypress and I faced a problem. I need to check received letter and click it. I case of letter received immediately it's simple I check that element present and after that ckick on the letter. I used something like this

```
**cy.get("body").then($body => {
    if ($body.find("button[data-cy=appDrawerOpener]").length > 0) { 
      cy.get("button[data-cy=appDrawerOpener]")
        .click();
    }**
```

But I don't understend how can I check the letter if i receive it for example after 2 minutes. What logical condition Should I create?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a 2 minute timeout. As soon as the element appears the test succeeds, if it does not appear after 2 minutes the test fails.

```
cy.get("button[data-cy=appDrawerOpener]", { timeout: 120000 }) // in ms
  .click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function that calls itself recursively with `setTimeout` until the element is found.

```
function find(){
    if ($body.find("button[data-cy=appDrawerOpener]").length > 0) { 
      cy.get("button[data-cy=appDrawerOpener]")
        .click();
    } else {
      setTimeout(find, 500);//500 millisecond delay
    }
}
find();
```

Comment: This is not quite what you need. I'm trying to waiting or retrying element visibility if element doesn't appear and I don't understand how I can do this ?

Comment: @Sergey Could you elaborate on what you need? It is not very clear to me.

Comment: @ hev1 I need to retry find element  if the element is not visible on the page.

Comment: @Sergey My answer does exactly that, does it not?